# Parsing string array into chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to parse a string array to be consumed by Highcharts. When the values are static, the chart renders. When the array is passed, it does not render. I validated the string being parsed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ucL9fw4q/).

The specific line is

```
//This works
chart.addSeries({name: this.series_name, color: this.series_color, data: [[0.129, 0.066], [0.029, 0.218], [-0.113, 0.231]]});

//This does not
chart.addSeries({name: this.series_name, color: this.series_color, data: series_clean});
```

Full

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'scatter',
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        series: [
            {data: []}
        ]
    });

    function reloadData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "...",
            dataType: "JSON"
        }).done(function(data) {
            //Remove existing series from chart
            while(chart.series.length > 0)
                chart.series[0].remove(true);

            var i = 0;
            $.each(data.users, function(firstIndex, user) {
                $.each(user, function() {
                    //Parse incoming data array to float type
                    var series_clean = new Array();

                    var series_data_groups = this.series_data.split("|");

                    for(var j = 0; j < series_data_groups.length; j++) {
                        var series_data_values = series_data_groups[j].split(",");
                        var x = parseFloat(series_data_values[0]).toFixed(3);
                        var y = parseFloat(series_data_values[1]).toFixed(3);
                        series_clean.push([x, y]);
                    }

                    //Push series to chart
                    chart.addSeries({name: this.series_name, color: this.series_color, data: series_clean});
                    i++;
                });
            });

            chart.redraw();
        });
    }

    setInterval(function(){reloadData(); }, 2000);
});
```

Console error

```
Uncaught Error: Highcharts error #14: www.highcharts.com/errors/14
    at Object.a.error (highcharts.js:10)
    at n.setData (highcharts.js:284)
    at n.init (highcharts.js:277)
    at a.Chart.initSeries (highcharts.js:243)
    at highcharts.js:317
    at a.fireEvent (highcharts.js:29)
    at a.Chart.addSeries (highcharts.js:317)
    at Object.<anonymous> (chart_scatter_live2.html:109)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.2.0.min.js:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (chart_scatter_live2.html:95)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x` and `y` are strings since `toFixed()` returns a string at:

```
var x = parseFloat(series_data_values[0]).toFixed(3);
var y = parseFloat(series_data_values[1]).toFixed(3);
```

This causes the `Highcharts Error #14 - String value sent to series.data, expected Number`